# Unable to access codeigniter controller in Live Server but accessible in localhost (xampp on windows)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

My project working fine on local system (XAMPP) , however when uploaded to hosting server its not working. Im Using Codeigniter framework. accesible in localhost via "localhost/myproject/controller" , but in host server unable to access via myproject.com/controller or even myproject.com/index.php/controller !!

On server, main domain is (lets suppose D.COM and add on domain is AD.COM). My application is installed under addon domain. hence my folder structure is

```
public html/
            AD.COM/
                  application/
                              Config
                              Controllers
                              Modules
                              Views
                  System/
                 User_guide/
                .htaccess
```

.htaccess contains this code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also maintained these variables

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

how to fix this. I tried googling but didnt get any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your live site URL??

Comment: does it show anything if you access the index page, like myproject.com (no controller)?

Comment: right now im uncomfortable to say that, how ever my host server OS is LINUX.

Comment: yes, it shows the default welcome controller on live server. ie when opened myproject.com               @webcrazymaniac

Comment: what is your live website URL??

Comment: I don't really get the dir structure: is codeigniter in main directory or in secondary directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be concern about **Codeigniter naming conversion** and Keep mind **Linux host is Case-Sensitive**.

You are not providing any resources related to your question.  So have to tell is check about **Spellings** of your *url* and *controller names* and *methods* which you will call further.

Comment: how I missed this thing. I am calling controllers with Lower Cases while it is defined as Camel Cased. Thanks for prompt response.